# Debugging a custom language with WinDBG

Tags: debugging, winapi, windbg

Is it possible to extend WinDBG somehow to support a custom native language? I've found the Debug Engine API, which provides client interfaces to things like the symbol store, but I haven't seen much about creating your own implementations of these technologies. Specifically, I'm wondering if source-level debugging, along with locals could be implemented.

I'm guessing no, but it's worth asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DbgHelp.dll is ultimately where all of this symbol handling occurs. To work with something other than PDB you would need to replace or augment the functionality provided there.

In the end, I think you would have a very hard time convincing WinDbg to work with a different debug format than PDB. Not saying that it couldn't be done, just that it's not really something that it's designed to make easy.